# Can "constant" lookups be done efficiently within a single query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

Pop quiz, SQL Server hotshots:

How many times will the following `student` subquery be executed? (assuming there are at least ten rows in `something`):

```
SELECT TOP 10 a, b
     , (SELECT type_id
          FROM type
         WHERE type_code = 'student') student
  FROM something
```

If you said 1, then like me, you assume SQL Server would recognize the value of `student` as an invariant scalar.

Unfortunately, the answer is 10:

[image: Execution plan for inline select and CTE versions]

[image: Index seek details for inline and CTE execution plan]

I know, I'll use a CTE!

```
WITH codes (student) AS (
    SELECT (SELECT type_id
              FROM type
             WHERE type_code = 'student')
)
SELECT TOP 10 a, b
     , student
  FROM something
 CROSS JOIN codes
```

The result is exactly the same.

Of course, I can get the desired efficiency by first capturing the scalar to a variable:

```
DECLARE @Student tinyint
SELECT @Student = type_id
  FROM type
 WHERE type_code = 'student'

SELECT TOP 10 a, b
     , @Student student
  FROM something
```

This only does one seek, and adds nothing to the main query plan:

[image: Execution plan for scalar pre-stored in variable]

But besides being more verbose, if you're defining an inline table-valued function, it means you also have to write out an otherwise implicit return schema, which is a pain (and adds a vector for errors).

Is there any way to write a single query that only runs the subquery once?

Comment: Out of interest, is it the TOP 10 that's causing this behaviour?  And, if so, what happens if you put the TOP 10  in a sub query, then use your different options to 'join'/'append' your scalar constant?

Comment: @MatBailie, that *is* interesting.  The `TOP 0` was just to "simplify" the example, but it did impact the results.  When I remove it, I do in fact get one seek, but it also adds a "Table Spool" that's done once for each row, at 90% overall cost.  So it's good to know that this has unexpected effects, but the suggestions from the accepted answer still end up simpler and more efficient than the original—along the lines of what I expected in the first place.  That's what happens when an "MWE" is not quite "M" enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 a, b,
      (SELECT type_id FROM type WHERE type_code = 'student'
      ) as student
FROM something;
```

You want an index on `type(type_code, type_id)`.

You might find this more efficient if you move the subquery to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT TOP 10 a, b,
       t.type_id
FROM something s CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT type_id FROM type WHERE type_code = 'student'
     ) t
```

Or even:

```
SELECT TOP 10 s.a, s.b, t.type_id
FROM something s JOIN
     type t
     ON t.type_code = 'student';
```

Comment: The problem is not that an index isn't being used (it is)—it's that it's being used *on every row* to look up the same value.  I have a `UNIQUE` constraint on `type_code` that implicitly creates an index, which the plan indicates is being used.  Still, I tried your suggestion and I got the same result.

Comment: @harpo . . . Right.  The correct solution is to move the subquery to the `FROM`.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon!  Both of those result in one lookup on the type table.  I would expect the `CROSS JOIN` in particular to be semantically indistinguishable from my CTE version. I did the scalar there as a subselect because in practice there's more than one code lookup.  Anyway, thanks again for the suggestions!